# React Component doesnt recognize object properties to use as values received from Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

My title is probably a bit confusing, but I couldn't think of a better one.
From my back end I am sending data through socket.io events to my react front end.
The data I am sending is something like this:

```
{
  " 1": { Val: 1, ID: 2, Comment: "hello"},
  ...
}
```

On my react front end I am indeed receiving the data, I have a state to save it and effect to retrieve it:

```
const [regData, setRegData] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("DataEvent", (RegData) => {
    const newRegData = RegData;
    setRegData(newRegData);
    console.log(regData);
  });
}, [regData]);
```

The console log correctly outputs the data in the browser console.

Then I have a component where I want to display some of that data:

```
<Button text={`${regData}`}></Button>
```

And this is the actual component:

```
export default function Button({ text }) {
  return (
    <div className="btn card-element">
      {text}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I run the code like this, first I get undefined for a brief second until it starts receiving the data and then object-Object as expected.

The problem is when I try to get an actual value out of that object

If I do `${regData[" 1"]}` I still get the undefined and then object-Object, expected again.

But if I do `${regData[" 1"].Val}` or even just `regData[" 1"].Val`, I get an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Val' of undefined

I guess I am getting the error, because my regData in the initial state is undefined and it tries to access Val of undefined. Ok, but isnt `useEffect` supposed to solve this?

Also I have noticed that if I `console.log(newRegData)` it always, always, always gives me the full object which makes me wonder why when I am `console.log(regData)`-ing I sometimes get an empty object?

EDIT (solved): Screenshot of the empty objects - http://prntscr.com/tg8l73 looking at it I have even noticed a pattern, first I get 1 empty object and no data object, then I get one empty object and one data object, then I get one empty object and 2 data objects, so on every "iteration" I get one extra data object, but there always is an empty object before that, but I am always receiving an object. I let it run for a while and I got to a point where I got 1 empty object and 50 data objects, and I think its just spilling them out all at the same time, its not like 1 by 1.

EDIT 2 (solved): I figured that the incremental output of data objects is, because I am monitoring regData and the moment I receive it it triggets the useEffect again and it snowballs. So I left it at an empty array, that fixed the snowballing, but now I only get empty objects: http://prntscr.com/tg8ndy

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("DataEvent", (RegData) => {
    setRegData(RegData);
    console.log(regData);
  });
}, []);
```

EDIT 3....: I tried console.logging regData elsewhere and it does have the data inside it, so that seems to not be an issue after all. Back to the undefined Val.

Comment: `setRegData` is async so `console.log` after `setRegData(RegData);` will gives you the old value.

Comment: Allright, that makes sense, thanks. Do you know how to solve my other issue?

Comment: If I understand the issue correctly, at the beginning, `regData` is `undefined` so `regData[" 1"].Val` throws an error. In order to handle that case too, you can do something like `regData ? regData[" 1"].Val : ''` or `regData?.[" 1"]?.Val`

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes that is the issue, I have just tried regData ? regData[" 11"].Val : "" and it didnt work, gives me the same error. Also, I have much more data than this and this doesnt seem like a good way to solve it, since I will have to pollute my code with these ternaries in every single place where I have to use that data, just to handle the first few iterations when there is no data. Isnt thre a way to make React wait until I actually get the data?

Comment: P.S. 11 is the actual data I am trying to access, " 1" was just an example, thats why in the copy/pasted code in my response it is " 11"

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to render the entire content of the component only when `regData` is ready. If so, you can add a condition at the beginning of the `return` statement of the component. Something like `return regData ? <><Button text={`${regData[" 11"]}`}></Button>....</> : null;`

Comment: @MoshFeu okay that worked, and I understood why it wasnt working initially, because in the useState I've given it a default value of {} so the condition was always true, I removed that and it is now working. Now whenever the value changes, is it going to re-render everything because of that condition, or is it just going to update the specific place with the value, like it normally should? How is that exactly working behind the scenes? When regData changes it is re-evaluation the expression and eventually rendering my components with the correct data coming from regData

Comment: ... but what happens when the regData object changes, is it going to re-evaluate the expression and re-render everything, or if for example regData[" 15"].Val changes, it is only going to update the component that uses that particular value and not re-render the whole thing ?

Comment: Yeah, it is re-rendering everything I added a console log inside the return and it goes on forever. regData is an object that I am receiving every 1 second or so. Even thought it is the same object that I am receiving, it is re-rendering all components, not just the ones that are using a particular value.  return regData ? (
    <>
      {console.log("RENDERING")}
       <ABunchOfComponentsUsingRegData></.....>
   </>) : null;

Comment: It's re-rendering all. First, it's not "evaluates" `regData` but compare references so every time `regData` has a new reference (the whole object comes from the server for example) it will re-render all the children components. Maybe if you update only the relevant child (e.g. "15") you can avoid those re-renders.

Comment: No value is being updated, just information is bring sent all the time, regardless of if its changed, so objexts are the same everytime there is jo change yet it gets triggered and rerenders everything. There should be a way to do this cleanly.

Comment: If the content is not changed, you can use `useMemo` to capture the **reference** or you can use https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect